# logoutRedirect() is not working in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.3

In my app controller i defined as

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
       // 'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admin_logins', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admin_logins', 'action' => 'index'),
            'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
            'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.',
            'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'))
            )

    ));
..........
?>
```

If session timeout instead of redirecting into `admin_logins/index` it redirects to `users/login`,

I printed logoutRedirect url inside `beforeFilter()` in app controller as below

```
// only allow the login controllers only
    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
        pr($this->Auth->logoutRedirect); die;
}
```

It prints like below

```
Array
(
    [controller] => admin_logins
    [action] => index
)
```

But still it redirects to `users/login` Can someone suggest here?

Answer (score 0):

Its my mistake. I missed to define the `loginAction` in my `AppController`. After modifying my `$components` it is working fine.

```
public $components = array(
       // 'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admin_logins', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
            'loginAction'=>array('controller'=>'admin_logins', 'action'=>'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admin_logins', 'action' => 'index'),
            'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
            'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.',
            'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'))
            )

    ));
```